# ¿Como sacar el total por país?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente información necesito sacar el total pero por país mysql

He intentado con esta consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(PAIS) AS TOTAL_PAIS
                FROM TABLA
                WHERE NUMBER <> '-1'
                 AND NUMBER NOT LIKE '569%'
                 AND FECHA = '20181115'
```

y el resultado es :

```
**SIN COINCIDENCIAS**
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Argentina
Brazil
Canada
Canada
Colombia
Colombia
Colombia
Colombia
Colombia
Costa Rica
Costa Rica
Costa Rica
Costa Rica
Dominican Republic
France
France
France
France
France
France
Guatemala
Iceland
Iceland
Italy
Mexico
Mexico
Netherlands
Netherlands
Paraguay
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Peru
Russian Federation
Spain
Spain
Spain
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
Uruguay
Uruguay
Uruguay
Uruguay
```

El resultado que deseo obtener:

**TOTAL PAISES: 19**

Comment: y el query , para saber que intentastes

Comment: yo creo que lo que quisiste decir es el total de paises unicos de esa lista. Es un query trivial. Sabes SQL? intentaste algo?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta, con la SQL que he intentado

Comment: Y miraste la documentacion de count? porque ya lo tienes.. solo te falta un detallecito...

Comment: No, Con la consulta que tengo me muestra un listado de todos los paises pero quiero un total sin contar los registros que se repitan me explico ?

Comment: SI si. Lo que te estoy preguntando es si miraste la documentacion de count. Porque alli se explica lo que vos queres...

Comment: No lo he visto..

Comment: Recuerda que se pide que no solamente intentes algo, si no que investigues al respecto. Lo que pedis, se soluciona agregando un group by, o haciendo un distinct de la tabla. todas esas opciones, estan bien documentadas.

Comment: Si me funciono con el distinct

Comment: y si haces `SELECT pais, count(*) FROM total_pais group by pais";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer con el comando '`distinct`' además recomiendo usar siempre el comando `ORDER BY` junto con este, ya que si los registros no están ordenados no hace la distinciones correctamente

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT PAIS) AS TOTAL_PAIS
            FROM TABLA
            WHERE NUMBER <> '-1'
             AND NUMBER NOT LIKE '569%'
             AND FECHA = '20181115'. ORDER BY pais
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar solo un registro por pais

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAIS AS TOTAL_PAIS
FROM TABLA
WHERE NUMBER <> '-1'
AND NUMBER NOT LIKE '569%'
AND FECHA = '20181115'
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas

Comment: porque usar el AS ?? no creo que sea necesario en esa sentencia....

Comment: el uso de "as" es solo para darle un "alias" al campo, en este caso efectivamente no es necesario, su uso es mas conveniente para el caso de operaciones, ej. "SELECT (campo1+campo2) as TOTAL..."

Answer (score 0):

Al final deberías hacer `GROUP BY` país puesto que al usar una función de agregación `COUNT()`
Ocupas agrupar el resultado de datos

Entonces pon

```
GROUP BY país;
```

Con eso mostrará la lista de países y su total pero agrupando por aquellos registros que pertenezcan al mismo país; es decir en vez de mostrar 20 registros que digan argentina, solo mostrará uno y enfrente el resultado de la función `COUNT` por ejemplo 20

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(PAIS) AS TOTAL_PAIS
                FROM TABLA
                WHERE NUMBER <> '-1'
                 AND NUMBER NOT LIKE '569%'
                 AND FECHA = '20181115'
                GROUP BY pais
```

El `group by` te los agrupa sin mostrar repetidos, y el `count(pais)` te mostrara la total para cada grupo de pais.